# Erlang calculating HMAC-SHA1 example?

Tags: erlang, sha1, hmac

Any examples or libraries to caculate HMAC-SHA1 in Erlang?

I tried Crypto Module, but apparently doesn't match exactly. Any examples?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To expand on the previous answer, here is the hmac module in Python using the SHA-1 algorithm with the key 'hello' and the message 'world':

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import hmac
>>> hmac.HMAC(key='hello', msg='world', digestmod=hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
'8a3a84bcd0d0065e97f175d370447c7d02e00973'
```

Here's the equivalent in Erlang. I'd use a more efficient method to convert the binary MAC to a hex digest in typical code, but I used this one for brevity:

```
1> crypto:start().
ok
2> <<Mac:160/integer>> = crypto:hmac(sha, <<"hello">>, <<"world">>).
<<138,58,132,188,208,208,6,94,151,241,117,211,112,68,124,
  125,2,224,9,115>>
3> lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~40.16.0b", [Mac])). 
"8a3a84bcd0d0065e97f175d370447c7d02e00973"
```

Comment: crypto:sha_mac/2 is deprecated, replaced with crypto:hmac/3    You're better of this way: `<<Mac:160/integer>> = crypto:hmac(sha,<<"hello">>, <<"world">>).`

Comment: That interface did not exist in 2010, when this answer was written. I believe this API was added rather recently in an R16 release. You're welcome to propose an edit.

Answer (score 2):

The sha_mac function in the crypto module is HMAC-SHA1:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#sha_mac-2

The reason it might not match is because you're probably comparing it to a "hexdigest", not the raw digest data.

Comment: Issue solved. The Erlang one was correct and the C libraries I was using is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
string:to_lower(lists:flatten([[integer_to_list(N, 16) || <<N:4>> <= crypto:sha_mac("hello", "world")]])).
```

Comment: Please explain. A single line of code is not considered sufficient as an answer.